# TFS (Azure DevOps) Notifications- Send a notification for deployment starting for a release

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to setup a notification in TFS that notifies people via e-mail that a deployment is starting. I tried experimenting with custom notifications but it seems that there is no way to do this. Is there any way to send a notification like this via TFS?

Comment: Yes Cece, thank you. Im going to meet with the TFS gurus in my company so I can look into setting up service hook events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such setting in Notification to send an email when a deployment is starting by default. But there are event type of `Release deployment started` available:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#ms.vss-release.deployment-started-event

You could run tasks on other services when events happen in your Azure DevOps Services projects. For example, Microsoft Teams, Office 365, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops